# Internal consistency

Tags: ranking, agreement-statistics, ranks, item-analysis

I have to analyse a dataset in which there are drugs and used animals based on article review. The datasets looks like this:

```
              rat      mice       dogs    ...
Drug1          5         10          7
Drug2          3          2          9
   ..
```

In the above table numbers show article number in which the given animal was used by given drug. There are more drugs and animals, of course. The question is whether there is a difference between usage.

Perhaps chi-squared could check association, but it can't tell ranks. Spearman is not good either. I identified ranks using excel function for each drugs (top1,2,3,4,5) and calculated proportions with 95% CI-s.

Is there a better way to check ordered ranks? Do I need agreement (not rater but...). And sometimes top2 is the toplist, sometimes more than five. Do I have to weight rank by proportion?

Comment: "In the above table numbers show article number in which the given animal was used by given drug. " So rats were given drug 1 in 5 articles, or rats were given drug 1 in article 5?

Comment: First one. Drug1 in 5 articles.